# Swift 4 .symmetricDifference and others are not working

Tags: swift

First coding question ever!

So I'm totally new at coding and I'm taking a course in Lynda.com
The course is for swift 4 but there are certain commands that are not working or I have to write it different in order for it to work.
For example
Course says: activeQuest.sorted() Does not work
activeQuest.sort() Does work

Course says: activeQuest.intersection(completedQuests) Does not work
activeQuest.intersect(completedQuests) Does work

.symmetricDifference does not work and couldn't find any other way to write it

Why is this? Thank you!

Comment: Nobody knows what activeQuest is.

Comment: Please paste the code where you create activeQuest as well as the code around the command that isn’t working as you expect. Then we’ll have some basis for helping you.

Comment: It was just an example to shot how to use sets, the problem was that I was using an older version of swift

This is the code>

var activeQuests: Set = ["Fetch Gemstones", "Big Boss", "The Undertaker", "Granny Needs Firewood"]
var completedQuests: Set = ["Big Boss", "All-4-One", "Hereafter"]

// Set operations
activeQuests.symmetricDifference(completedQuests)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is this?

It’s because the course is for Swift 4 but you are using an earlier version of Swift.